# Google maps android api v2 in fragment

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

Hy everyone.......
I've successfully got `Google maps android API v2` working 
but the google maps uses **FragmentActivity**  for displaying map
i want to use fragment to display the map inside
currently i m using this code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)           getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Error in Maps.class = " , e.toString());
    }
}
```

but instead of extending from FragmentActivity i wanna extend from Fragment i.e displaying map inside a fragment 
any help in this regard will be highly appreciated..
thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

If you have sucessfully installed the new maps V2 library then you should be able to just extend from "SupportMapFragment".

The Javadoc info is available here. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html